# Change APIARY GET URL parameters for testing in the built in REST client

Tags: rest, apiary.io, apiary

In Apiary we use http://baasar.apiary-mock.com/user/{appId}/{userId} where appId and userId are URL parameters.

Apiary has a builtin REST Client to test these APIs against a mockup and production API.

However, trying to test the above API, how do i change the appId and userId to something real in the Apiary REST client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to specify particular values for `{appId}` and `{userId}`, right?

Assuming by builtin REST Client, you mean Interactive console, so there is a tab with headline "URI Parameters", where you can fill values. Documentation is on https://docs.apiary.io/tools/interactive-documentation/#console.

I hope it helps, feel free to ask more.